# Prolog get list from different relations

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

i´d like to get a list from a graph. The variables with two letters are the points and the one letter is a line. Each line can contain multiple points.

```
conn(bs, oc, c).
conn(oc, tc, c).
conn(bs, gp, j).
conn(gp, cc, j).
conn(gp, pc, p).
conn(pc, ls, p).
conn(gp, oc, v).
conn(oc, pc, b).
conn(pc, cc, b).
conn(tc, ls, n).
conn(ls, cc, n).

link(X, Y, Z) :- conn(X, Y, Z), !.
link(X, Y, Z) :- conn(Y, X, Z).
```

Now i want to get a list with all points belonging to a line. By typing:

```
getpoints(c, X).
```

i would expect

```
X = [bs, oc, tc]
```

This is how i tried to get my result:

```
getpoints(Line, [First|[]]) :- not(link(First, _Second, Line)).
getpoints(Line, [First|Rest]) :- link(First, _Second, Line), getpoints(Line, Rest).
```

Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: i know i have the missing Points in the first Relations but i can´t edit the post anymore. But i tried it with the correct Syntax :-)

Comment: points, for `conn`, added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't interested in a particular order of points, you could use `setof/3`

By example

```
getpoints(Line, Points) :-
  setof(X, Y^(conn(X, Y, Line) ; conn(Y, X, Line)), Points).
```

**--- EDIT ---**

> Is it very complicadet to get the order of the points?

If you're point are really a line (not a more general graph), you can write something like

```
nextLine(Line, EndLine, []) :-
  \+ conn(EndLine, _, Line).

nextLine(Line, Start, [NextPoint | NextLine]) :-
  conn(Start, NextPoint, Line),
  nextLine(Line, NextPoint, NextLine).

getpoints(Line, [Start, NextPoint | NextLine]) :-
  conn(Start, NextPoint, Line),    
  \+ conn(_, Start, Line),
  nextLine(Line, NextPoint, NextLine).
```

The idea is find, in `getpoints/2`, the `Start` point of the line, that is the point that is on the left of a `conn/3` (`conn(Start, NextPoint, Line)`) but isn't on the right of a `conn/3` (`\+ conn(_, Start, Line)`).

In this way you have the first two point of the line and, calling `nextLine/3` recursively, you detect the following points in the correct order.

Comment: Is it very complicadet to get the order of the points? That would be awesome! But thanks for your anseer :-)

Comment: @bf2012 - the order of the point?... Let me think... no, I suppose not (not complicated) if `Line` really represent a line... let me play a while.